# How can one modify the **max-beans-in-free-pool** property for a given MDB via the Weblogic 10.3.1.0 Console?

Tags: java, server, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, message-driven-bean

How can one modify the **max-beans-in-free-pool** property for a given MDB via the Weblogic 10.3.1.0 Console ? I know this can be added in weblogic-ejb-jar.xml configuration file, but want to do this via Weblogic Console.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have that feature Admin Console in 10.3.1, not sure for later versions of WLS.

Answer (score 0):

According to [WebLogic documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/EJBPG/ejb_jar_ref.htm#EJBPG654), it defines a free pool size for EJBs and it's also a property which you could configure your MDB  but only using the *ejb-jar.xml* file and there's no way to do this in the console because it's something that belongs to the application.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/WLMDB/summary.htm#WLMDB1385) there is a set of possibles attributes to configure the MDB with annotations or only in the ejb-jar file for Weblogic